# React Native: FlatList not updating initial data with extraData

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

So I tried adding a searchbar that is supposed to update a flatlist, however, I can not make it update. The following code is what I've been trying to do.

```
const DeviceList: React.FC = () => {
  const fetcher = url => api.get(url).then(res => res.data);
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();
  const { data, error } = useSWR<Device[]>(
    // FETCH DATA FROM AN API
  );
  var fullData = data;
  var initialData = data;
  const [updatingData, setUpdatingData] = useState(data);
  
  const navigateToDevice = useCallback(
    (deviceId: string, device: Device, deviceName: string) => {
      navigate('Device', { deviceId, device , deviceName});
    },
    [navigate],
  );
  
  const contains = ({name}, query) => {
    if (name !== undefined){
      if (name.includes(query)){
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }

  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const updateSearch = (search) => {
    setSearch(search);
    setUpdatingData([...filter(fullData, device => {
      return contains(device, search);
    })])
  };
  
  const navigateToReader = useCallback(() => {
    navigate('Reader');
  }, [navigate]);

  if (!data) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Text>Loading</Text>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <SearchBar
        placeholder="Device Name"
        defaultValue=''
        onChangeText={updateSearch}
        value={search}
      />
      <DevicesList
        data={initialData}
        extraData={updatingData}
        keyExtractor={device => device.name}
        renderItem={({ item: device }) => (
          <DeviceContainer
            onPress={() => {
              navigateToDevice(device.device, device, device.name);
            }}
          >
            <DeviceIcon name="truck" size={24} color="black" />
            <DeviceName>{device.name}</DeviceName>
          </DeviceContainer>
        )}
      />
      <ButtonContainer>
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            navigateToReader();
          }}
        >
          Scan
        </Button>
      </ButtonContainer>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default DeviceList;
```

This will show me the list with all the device names when I boot the app up but the search bar will not work. If I set both of data and extraData to updatingData it will not show me anything when I boot the app up, however, the search will work. I have also tried updating the initialData variable inside the updateSearch function, however, it also did not work.

I would like to know how can I make it so that I can have both solutions working together, show the initial data AND have it update whenever I type something on the search bar.

EDIT:

As suggented by a comment I have tried to use the useEffect function to fetch my data, however, this is giving me an invalid hook call error.

Here is what I was trying to do:

```
const DeviceList: React.FC = () => {
  const fetcher = url => api.get(url).then(res => res.data);
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();
  const [fullData, setFullData] = useState<Device[]>();
  const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState<Device[]>();
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const { data, error } = useSWR<Device[]>(
      //API LINK,
      fetcher,
    );
    setFullData(data);
    setInitialData(data);
  }, []);
```

FINAL EDIT:
Adding the [data] parameter to the useEffect hook solved the problem. Thank you @Imasneri.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const { data, error } = useSWR<Device[]>(
      //API LINK,
      fetcher,
    );
    setFullData(data);
    setInitialData(data);
  }, [data]);
```

Comment: first of all put your fullData and initialData in an useState and while fetching setState for those two data.

Comment: I have tried doing that and it only leads me to the second problem which is when I boot up the app nothing is showing on the screen until I search for something that is why I was trying it like that.

Comment: You have to put your fetch inside a useEffect(() => {}, []);

Comment: Wont that make me call the api everytime the flat list is rendered ?

Comment: No the [] make it call only the first time the component is render https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp

Comment: I made an edit with the changes I made, I assume that is what you were suggesting ?

Comment: what is the error this is giving to you ?

Comment: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See LINK for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

From what I have seen in a github issue of SWR you can not use it inside useEffect. The problem is that whenever useEffect is called both fullData and initialData are still undefined if I log them

Comment: Yes you can't call useSwr inside useEffect try to use the api.get(url).then(res => res.data); directly in the useEffect without assigning it to the fetcher

Comment: Is there any way I can use the useSWR this way ? Maybe wait for it to fetch the data ? Because despite me setting initialData and fullData these still show up as being undefined.

Comment: if you transform your use effect this way you can redo:
useEffect(() => {
    setFullData(data);
    setInitialData(data);
  }, [data]);

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include the solution; post a stand-alone answer below so that it can be useful for others in the future (you can include giving credit for the answer - nothing wrong with this).